# как передать класс как массив?

Tags: c++

Я использую для программирования в opengl библиотеку glm. Я смотрел в glm и так и не понял как это делается. Меня интересует вот это. Как класс может передать себя как двумерный массив, хотя вроде внутренне он передаёт одномерный массив. но как это в c++ сделать простым способом? Вот пример о чем я говорю.

```
glm::mat4 proj;
        this->proj = glm::ortho ( 0.0f, width, 0.0f, height, 0.0f, 1.0f );
glUniformMatrix4fv ( this->proj_location, 1, GL_FALSE, &this->proj[0][0] );
```

Comment: оператор [ ] можно перегружать

Comment: А что не так с `&this->proj[0][0]`?

Comment: @user7860670 можно, но у меня получается только одномерный массив перегрузить, а тут двумерный, и я не пойму как это сделать?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat но я так понимаю что это класс, и если перегружен operator[], то как он перегружен, что можно написать так `&this->proj[0][0]`?

Comment: Надо чтобы перегруженный оператор [ ] возвращал ссылку на объект с перегруженным оператором [ ], тогда их можно будет вызвать два раза подряд.

Comment: @user7860670 а нука сделайте ответ, и я посмотрю как это. Или вы пишете в комментариях, потому что не уверены в ответе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В glm матрица определена как массив из четырёх векторов размерности 4:

```cpp
template<typename T, qualifier Q>
struct mat<4, 4, T, Q>
{
    typedef vec<4, T, Q> col_type;

private:
    col_type value[4];
```

Также для матрицы определён operator[], возвращающий *ссылку* на i-ый вектор:

```cpp
template<typename T, qualifier Q>
typename mat<4, 4, T, Q>::col_type & mat<4, 4, T, Q>::operator[](typename mat<4, 4, T, Q>::length_type i)
{
    return this->value[i];
}
```

Дальше. vec4 определён как `T x, y, z, w`. operator[] для вектора работает так: 
проверяется i, и в зависимости от его значения возвращается *ссылка* на соотвествующую координату:

```cpp
template<typename T, qualifier Q>
T& vec<4, T, Q>::operator[](typename vec<4, T, Q>::length_type i)
{
    assert(i >= 0 && i < this->length());
    switch(i)
    {
    default:
    case 0:
        return x;
    case 1:
        return y;
    case 2:
        return z;
    case 3:
        return w;
    }
}
```

Что имеем в итоге: proj[0] возвращает ссылку на вектор, и (proj[0])[0] возвращает ссылку на координату.
В памяти это выглядит вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
т.е. *последовательно*.
Именно это и имеет значение.
glUniformMatrix4fv просит массив из 16 элементов, что мы ему и предоставили